# Retrieve firebase realtime data using nodejs functions

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am starting with firebase and i have created a realtime database that contains an object. I want to retrieve that object using nodejs function from firebase and show it in console. So far i have created firebase project with nodejs but i am not sure how can i retrieve the data from my realtime database.

index.js file

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

let serviceAccount = require('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
```

realtime database in firebase

```
{
  "UpcomingClasses" : {
    "course" : "chemistry",
    "date" : "27-8-1996",
    "enrolled" : "string",
    "instructor" : "string",
    "location" : "string"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking one of the many tutorials out there. They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.